# What is the Japanese analogue of word "with"?

Tags: words

Suppose we have phrase:

> I will meet with Yamada

In Japanese it will be:

> 私は山田さんと会います。

I am interested to know how to say:

1. Cards with hieroglyphs (meaning that hieroglyphs are written on cards)
2. Potato with meat (in the same dish)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In this case "with" is used as a modifier, an adjectival phrase.

   It is a little bit dependent on the context. If you had a bunch of cards and wanted to refer to only those with hieroglyphs, you might use the particle の, if in a more general context you'd need a verb の/が 書かれた, so:

   > 象形文字のカード
   >
   > 象形文字の書かれたカード

   But if you refer to Egyptian hieroglyphs, maybe "drawn" would be better than "written":

   > 象形文字の描かれたカード
2. Here the two things are (or originally were) separate, so the particle と fits well:

   > ミートとポテト

   But it looks like a special case. For other ingredients an adjectival phrase could be used as well, for example:

   > たまごを乗せるラーメン